# I run the flutter app with ADB but the app is not shown in the menu

Tags: flutter, android-intent, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I run the flutter app with ADB but the app is not shown in the menu. But the app is open. I can able to reload and restart but the app is not shown in the menu. My use case is to share text to myapp. So i use receive intent share plugin. I try with another app. But it will show on the menu.

Comment: what "menu" are you referring to? The App List on the device? The share menu from wherever you are sharing the text from? Please clarify.

Comment: ya, app list or app drawer. I share the URL from youtube to my app.